# How to restrict input from user to a numeric value?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I've been searching on the internet and can't seem to find this answer
So does anyone know to how stop users from inputting letters where only numbers should be allowed?

This is what my code looks like so far.

```
public static double payCalculator(double hours, double basePay)
{
    double totalPay; 
    double overTime = 8.00 * 1.5;
    while(hours < 0 | hours > 60) {
        System.out.println("Cannot work more than 60 hours a week");
        System.out.println("Hours Work?");
        hours = in.nextDouble();
    }
    while(basePay < 8) {
        System.out.println("Base Pay cannot be less than 8");
        System.out.println("Base Pay?");
        basePay = in.nextDouble();
    }
    if 
        (hours <= 40){
        totalPay = hours*basePay;
    }
    else {
        totalPay = ((hours - 40)*overTime) + (40*basePay);
    }
    return totalPay;

}
public static void main (String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hours worked?");
    hours = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Base Pay?");
    basePay = in.nextDouble();
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
    totalPay = payCalculator(hours, basePay);
    System.out.println("Total Pay is " + df.format(totalPay));       
}
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You don't need to post your entire code to find the solution to your problem, please share only that part of your code which is related to your problem.

Comment: Seems to be a console application. Is a GUI with Swing input text field possible.

Comment: Sufiyan Ghori - all the code is related to my problem, I'm not sure where the answer would go.

Comment: @KorwynnWagstaff, not all the code is related, for instance, code in your `main` method is enough to understand what you are asking for, therefore there was no need to include `payCalculator()` method with your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume your are using `Scanner` to take input.

You can use `Scanner.hasNextDouble()` to verify it is the number, it returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as a `double` value using the `nextDouble()` method. The scanner does not advance past any input.

Consider this example, It will keep asking for the input unless the user provides it with a number,

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double dbl = 0.0;
    boolean isValid = false;
    while (isValid == false) {
        System.out.println("Input Number: ");
        // If input is number execute this,
        if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
            dbl = sc.nextDouble();
            isValid = true;
            System.out.println("OK");
        }
        // If input is not a number execute this block, 
        else {
            System.out.println("Error! Invalid number. Try again.");
        }
        sc.nextLine(); // discard any other data
    }
    sc.close();
```

**output**,

```
Input Number: 
adsads
Error! Invalid number. Try again.
Input Number: 
sdas
Error! Invalid number. Try again.
Input Number: 
hello
Error! Invalid number. Try again.
Input Number: 
hi
Error! Invalid number. Try again.
Input Number: 
2.0
OK
```